# Choose extension of :file component in asdf defsystem

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro

I am 90% sure the answer is in [this paragraph of the asdf documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/The-defsystem-grammar.html#Pathname-specifiers) , but I seem unable to grok it.
I am wondering if I am able to have source files that do not end in ".lisp" as file components. For example, usually I have something like

```
(asdf:defsystem #:hash-bang-lang
  :serial t
  :depends-on (#:named-readtables)
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "hash-bang-lang")))
```

As you can see the :file components do not specify the extension. I am wondering if I can load lisp files that do not end in ".lisp".

The reason I want this is a little odd but has no impact on the question so feel free to skip the next bit.

I have some file "test.mylang" and it starts with the following

```
(in-package :hash-bang-lang)
(in-readtable hash-bang)
#!mylang
..rest of file..
```

The `#!mylang` is a reader macro that gives my #'mylang function control of parsing the rest of the file. So if I had a parser for python I would use #!python and my #'python function will take up the parsing.
In those cases I would like to have the `.mylang` or `.py` extension so editors know instantly how to highlight the code, even though it's going to be loaded as lisp anyway.

Thanks folks

Comment: I think that by using `#p"foo.py"`, it might work (as in `(:file #p"foo.py")`.

Comment: Afraid not `Error while trying to load definition for system hash-bang-lang .. There is no applicable method for the generic function .. FIND-COMPONENT .. when called with (#<ASDF:SYSTEM "hash-bang-lang"> #P"test.py")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:file` component type forces the file extension to `.lisp`. If you need some other extension, you need a new component type.

```
(defpackage #:mylang-system
  (:use #:cl #:asdf))
(in-package #:mylang-system)

(defclass mylang-file (cl-source-file)
  ((type :initform "mylang")))

(defsystem test-ext
  :encoding :utf-8
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:mylang-file "hash-bang-lang")))
```

Comment: Thanks, this will give me an excuse to look into the asdf extension mechanisms, that has been on my todo list for a while